# Do successive differences give you the exact degree of a polynomial or just a lower bound?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If you apply successive differences to the sampled polynomial function:

[image]

you get a get a degree of 3, not 4 ($f(x)= x^4$). Should we say that successive differences indicate the exact degree of a polynomial provided it is less than or equal to $n-1 $ ? or should we say, more generally, that it merely provides a lower bound?

Comment: You only have four points, so there is a degree 3 polynomial that fits them.

Comment: Correct, Karl. Do successive differences just provide a lower bound for the degree then?

Comment: is $x$ real? if not, what does continuous mean?

Comment: I wouldn't say they provide a lower bound. They tell you the exact degree of the lowest-degree polynomial that goes through the given points. In your example this polynomial is $8 x^3 - 14 x^2 - 8 x + 15.$

Comment: There are infinitely many other functions (including polynomials of degree $>3$ and many non-polynomial functions) that go through the same four points.